# Ant via Jenkins: "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" in Console Output while build is still running

Tags: java, windows, ant, build, jenkins

- Windows 7 x32
- Ant 1.6.5
- Jenkins 1.499
- Java 1.6.0_20

---

Jenkins' build command line is `run_ant.bat publish` (where `publish` is the Ant target):

- `run_ant.bat` file (incomplete):

```
call %ANT_HOME%\bin\ant.bat %1
exit
```

- main `build.xml` file (incomplete):

```xml
<target name="publish" depends="-init">
    <ant dir="${project.dev}" target="publish" />
</target>
```

---

After a while (and several Ant log lines), Jenkins' Console Output displays:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: X minutes Y seconds
```

But Jenkins' build still has its "in progress" status and there is still the [image: spinner] spinner at the end of the Console Output. Any idea what is happening here? It seems that Ant well finishes its tasks but that Jenkins is not informed about it...

---

May this help, most of the `java`, `javac` and `junit` Ant tasks are launched externally, i.e. using the `fork="yes"` option...

Comment: Side note: well done for getting the spinner in your question! :-)

Comment: I get the same thing on my Jenkins builds if I have some tasks to execute after the Ant build wraps up.  Things like publishing JUnit results, archiving build artifacts, emailing the development team, etc. all take some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `Build Successful` message is from your Ant process completing. If you run Ant on the command line, you see the same message. Jenkins, will print out `Finished: Success` when it actually completes the entire build and does all post-build processing.

If you do any post-build stuff (email on bad builds, run the CI game, archive artifacts, display unit test results, etc.) the Jenkins build will continue long after the `Build Successful` message. In one of my builds, Jenkins takes an extra three minutes to *complete* my build after that *Build Successful* message.